# MySql trigger on insert (error)

Tags: mysql, triggers, insert

this is my trigger:

```
CREATE TRIGGER update_avatar 
BEFORE INSERT ON `tbl_archivos` FOR EACH ROW
UPDATE `tbl_archivos` 
SET `is_avatar`='0' 
WHERE `tbl_usuarios_id_usuario`=NEW.`tbl_usuarios_id_usuario`
```

and this is the error:

```
#1442 - Can't update table 'tbl_archivos' in stored function/trigger because it is already used by statement which invoked this stored function/trigger.
```

i want to update the state "is_avatar" to 0 on upload file, where the id_usuario = the inserted id_usuario.

Whats wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It doesn't work because you are running an `UPDATE` inside a `INSERT` trigger - both statements modify the same table. There doesn't appear to be a way to use a trigger in MySQL that loops over all rows in a table when activated.

It is possible alter the values of columns of a row being modified look at example [in this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17295051/error-1442-mysql-making-a-trigger).

Solution to your problem (as variant) might include building some app to call some procedure, which will update data in your table, at a given interval or it is possible also use a cron job for that.

Comment: Or make a new table named 'preferences' where i define the current avatar.

comming from MySql, thats really stupid.

But thank you for answer.

Answer (score 0):

The error message is self-explanatory. MySQL still doesn't allow to issue any DML statements (insert, update, delete) on a table (in your case `tbl_archivos`) on which you defined the trigger.

The only thing you can do is to alter the values of columns of a row being inserted/updated in a `BEFORE` trigger.

Comment: The question appears to be potentially useful use case for triggers. Why is it not allowed? I don't see the rationale behind why the same table being inserted to can't be updated `BEFORE INSERT` or even `AFTER INSERT`.

Comment: @ADTC There were already some attempts to figure out this. For example look at this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6756454/what-is-the-real-cause-of-mysql-error-1442

Comment: Apparently a comment in that link suggests that you can indeed update the same table you're inserting to by using a function.

Comment: @Myshov Nvm.. I tried it in SQLFiddle. It still gives the same error, even if tried to update through a [function](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/5e9a6c) or [procedure](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/9beaad).

Comment: @ADTC For the topic question there is no solutions via triggers as I said already in my answer to the topic. There is no way to use a trigger in MySQL that loops over all rows in a table when activated. Just look at this article please for more details http://mark.koli.ch/2009/07/mysql-trigger-error-1442-hy000-cant-update-table-tbl-in-stored-functiontrigger-because-it-is-al.html